# Salesforce to WordPress Integration tools

Tags: website-integration

Can anyone recommend any good Salesforce to WordPress integration tools for creating dynamic forms that can create parent, child and even grandchild records chained together? I'm looking for a service like FormAssembly or the like (and the SFDC integration they provide) that is native to WordPress. I'm also interested in find out what kind of integration tools are out there to surface data from Salesforce to my WordPress website. Thanks in advance for any good pointers. Apps are fine but even consultant recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Greenstork -- thanks for pointing out FormAssembly. We have a Wordpress plugin via the 'publish' tab within the form. jaret [at] formassembly dot com should you wish to reach me.

Comment: Anyone have any updates to add here? Looks like there's a lot of activity in this space in the past 4 years.

Answer (score 3):

Gravity forms is a great form building tool for Wordpress and they have a Salesforce integration addon.  Sounds like this is exactly what you're looking for.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-salesforce/

Answer (score 1):

The standard Salesforce Web to Lead functionality, and the corresponding [Wordpress to Salesforce Leads plugin](http://daddyanalytics.com/wordpress-salesforce/) that also provides a few other features, won't be able to do what you want. The Web to Lead functionality is pretty low-tech by design.

And, Salesforce also prevents you from creating Master-Detail relationships on Leads, and many consultants will discourage you from using lookups to Leads as that Lead will be inaccessible from the UI once converted anyway. So what you're talking about will require someone to have done some significant custom coding (either as an existing plugin, or your own coding).

The two solutions mentioned so far will do this - Gravity Forms will provide this, as will Form Assembly. There are a few other form providers out there that can help (just look on the AppExchange), though Wufoo is not an option, as its Salesforce integration can only handle standard Salesforce fields.

Or, you can custom code this yourself, and you may have to if you want people to update information in Salesforce from within Wordpress. FormAssembly can be used to update info in Salesforce but I've only seen that when people are mailed a custom URL that pre-populates a form.

Finally, if all of this looks like a lot of coding, you might want to have a read-only Wordpress website and have people login to a backend [Customer Communities site within Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/communities/faq/).

Good luck!